# FileSystemWatcher error

Tags: vb.net, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to use `FileSystemWatcher` to *notify my program if any text file which has been opened externally is modified or not (like Notepad++)*. If the text file has been opened in my program and it has also been opened externally and has been modified then it has to let my program know.

I've created my `FileSystemWatcher` as follows:

```
Public Sub Watch()
    Dim watcher As New IO.FileSystemWatcher()

    'For watching current directory
    watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Var.SaveLocation) 'Note how to obtain current directory
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite Or NotifyFilters.FileName
    watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(Var.SaveLocation)

    AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged

    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub OnChanged(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Reload")
End Sub
```

I've added the `Watch()` method into the OpenFileDialog method in my program. So whenever a new text file is opened, the `FileSystemWatcher` starts. My problem is that if I save the text file which I opened within my program, the `OnChanged` event gets activated. It works fine when the text file is externally modified. It works the way it should however when I save the file within my program that event triggers. I don't want this as it shouldn't trigger while I'm in my program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to specifically exclude files or applications in the filesystemwatcher. One workaround would be to add a file name to a list when it is saved, then check that list (and remove the file) in the filesystemwatcher handler.

Comment: How can I do that? is providing me with an example possible?

Comment: In the Changed event, you can use e.FullPath to see what file has been changed, and e.ChangeType for the type of change. Check to see if e.FullPath is a file that has been saved by the application.